# Responsive images in container Bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I just finished my new custom Bootstrap Wordpress theme and added a carousel. It works fine, except it's not responsive. The images get pulled out to an unwanted height. I tried everything, but I can't seem to fix it.

Here it is on my website (with uncompressed css): http://your-juliet.net

Does anyone have a clue? I won't mind removing the caption on the carousel in smaller resolutions (but I rather not). Thanks so much!

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hty2jyj0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, deleted all the custom styling and put the carousel in a col